# ANTLR: Mismatched input for a simple grammar

Tags: antlr4

I've got a grammar like this to generate a parser:

```
grammar MyLang;

init: TERMINAL;

TERMINAL: '"' ~('"')* '"';
```

Using ANTLR4 and the grammar above to parse a simple input like "data", I've got an error:

```
mismatched input "data" expecting TERMINAL
```

I've read many questions against this error. But I can't figure out how to solve it. Would you pls let me know if there's anything wrong?

Comment: Which antlr4 version are you using? I tried your grammar with antlr 4.4, it works.

Comment: You probably forgot to regenerate the lexer and parser classes: your input `"data"` will parse just fine with a parser generated from the provided grammar. Voting to close since this can't be reproduced in any version of ANTLR 4 (or v3 for that matter).

Comment: Sorry all you guys! It's mine programming fault :(